# Error in AsyncTask with ImageView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask, imageview

I'm making a project to my University. But I try learn the AsyncTask in half an hour. HARD!
I make a game of "Simon" and I need that colors flash for one second, one after the other. But I'm not understanding the error and how solve...

Sorry my English, i'm Brazilian.

That is my AsyncTask Class...

```
package com.example.genius;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Queue extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ImageView> {
    protected ImageView doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ImageView imagem;
        int i = GameActivity.numCor;
        imagem = GameActivity.cor;
        if(i == 0)
            imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenlight);
        if(i == 1)
            imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.redlight);
        if(i == 2)
            imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowlight);
        if(i == 3)
            imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluelight);
        return imagem;
    }

    protected ImageView onPostExecute() {
        ImageView imagem;
        int i = GameActivity.numCor;
        imagem = GameActivity.cor;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e) {}

        if(i == 0)
            imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
        if(i == 1)
            imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
        if(i == 2)
            imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
        if(i == 3)
            imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
        return imagem;
    }
}
```

and that the method of my GameActivity, where I call the AsyncTask Class...

```
public void PiscarVerde() {

            numCor = 0;
            cor = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.green);
            Queue queue = new Queue();
            final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gr);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            queue.execute();
}
```

Can help me with this? Thank's

Comment: So, what is the error you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Your onPostExecute has wrong signature, change:

```
protected ImageView onPostExecute() {
```

to

```
protected void onPostExecute(ImageView result) {
```

also you dont really write whats wrong, where is the problem

btw. in Java a good practice is to add @Override annotation when overriding method, compiler will output errors in case you made an error, example:

```
@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(ImageView result) {
```

Answer (score 0):

=Your onPostExecute has wrong signature, change:

> protected ImageView onPostExecute(){..}

to

> protected void onPostExecute(ImageView imagem) {..}

An AsyncTask not realy complicated to use, you have 3 main step :

```
    //You have to do some init if needed 
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    //The background task do your async stuff
    protected ImageView doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    //In this part do stuff to update your UI
    protected void onPostExecute(ImageView imageView) {
        super.onPostExecute(imageView);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onPostExecute needs to return void.You might also wanna use a weak reference to your ImageView as it is recommended by Android Developers. You can check out how it is done here:
[Link to Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)